# Как убрать текст под значком в tabbar в react-native?

Tags: react-native

В общем суть такова. Библиотека react-native-router-flux Нужно убрать текст под значком в TabBar:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот собственно и код роутера:

```
const TabBar = ({focused}) => (
    <View>
        <Icon name="search" type="MaterialIcons" style={{fontSize: 28, color: focused ? 'red': 'white'}} />
    </View>
)

export default () => (
    <Router>
        <Scene hideNavBar>

            <Scene key="tabbar" tabs tabBarStyle={{backgroundColor: '#000'}}>

                <Scene key="list" title="Ahlo" component={List} hideNavBar icon={TabBar} />

                <Scene key="search" component={search} hideNavBar icon={TabBar} />

                <Scene key="account" component={account} hideNavBar icon={TabBar} />
            </Scene>

            <Scene key="article" component={article} />

            <Scene key="comment" component={comment} />

            <Scene key="register" component={register} />

            <Scene key="auth" component={auth} />
        </Scene>
    </Router>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть свойство showLabel - нужно поставить ему значение False